# Return a variable from a function to a view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am a newbie in laravel 4 and want to return, when pressing a button, a value from a controller to the view.

My form view:

```
            {{ Form::submit('Save', array('class' => 'btn btn-small btn-info iframe')) }}
            <?php
            echo $test;
            ?>
```

My Controller:

```
<?php
class TestController extends BaseController {


    /**
     * Start scrapping script.
     */
    public function postTest() {
        $scrap = 'It works!';

        return View::make ( 'admin/test/index' )->with('test', $test);
    }
}
```

My routes:

```
Route::post('test', 'TestController@postTest');
```

However, I get:

```
Undefined variable: test(View: C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel_project\lara\app\views\admin\test\index.blade.php)
```

Any recommendations what I am doing wrong?

I appreciate your answer!

**UPDATE**

I now changed my controller like that:

```
public function getIndex() {

    // Show the page
    return View::make ( 'admin/test/index' );
}

public function postTest() {
    $test = 'It works!';

    return View::make ( 'admin/test/index' )->with('test', $test);
}
```

}

and added to my routes file:

```
Route::get('test', 'TestController@getIndex');
Route::post('test', 'TestController@postTest');
Route::controller('test', 'TestController');
```

Furthermore, when calling:

```
                {{ $test}}
```

I get `Undefined variable: $test`

Any recommendations what I am doing wrong?

Comment: For you edit, read my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change in your controller:

```
return View::make ( 'admin/test/index' )->with('test', $test);
```

to:

```
return View::make ( 'admin/test/index' )->with('test', $scrap);
```

Now you are getting undefined warning because there is no `$test` variable in controller.

And in Blade view, you should display it using:

```
{{ $test }}
```

or

```
{{{ $test }}}
```

(the second one for escaping characters) and not `<?php echo $test; ?>`

Comment: Thx for your answer! However, I added a index function and now face the problem again. I would appreciate if you could have a look at my update!

Comment: @mrquad You need to define the same variable for `index` function:  return View::make ( 'admin/test/index' )->with('test','some value');

Comment: Thx for your answer! Sorry for this blunt question. Why can`t I just return here null without any value?

Comment: Furthermore, when pressing the button I now get now value back? Any explanation for this? I really appreciate your answer!

Comment: @mrquad You need to assign something to test if you use it in view. Other questions you need to ask as separate questions.

Answer (score 1):

```
$scrap = "Something";
return View::make ( 'admin/test/index' )->with(array('test' => $scrap));
```

Also, in your view, make sure you check that `$test` is actually present.

```
{{ Form::submit() ... }}
@if(isset($test))
{{ $test }}
@endif
```

OR (as per your edit) change getIndex to:

```
return View::make('admin/test/index')->with('test', '');
```

to avoid the undefined variable issue.

Comment: $test should also be $scrap in the controller

Comment: Thx for your answer! However, when pressing the button. Nothing appears on my screen ;(. So basically I just want to call the function, when my button is pressed.

Answer (score 1):

change to the following:

```
public function postTest() {

$test = 'It works!';
return View::make ( 'admin.test.index',['test' => $test] );

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your make to:

```
return View::make ( 'admin/test/index' )->with(array('test' => $test));
```

Additionally, if you look at your controller, the variable you give a value to is called $scrap while the one you assign to the view is called $test, I think you mean to give them both the same name (or else it will always be empty on the view).

Comment: `with(array('test' => $test))` does exactly the same as `with('test', $test)`